# How to set jenkins string parameter in Windows batch command

Tags: jenkins

I have declared a string parameter in Jenkins i.e "Year".
The value is to be set in windows batch command, because i thought this was simple without a plugin.
Below screen depicts on how i am setting the parameter Year.

[image]

When I do echo can see in the console correct data is displayed however when I try to use the same parameter after this execution in next set as **${params.Year}**, it seen as empty.

[image]

What I am doing wrong here? not able to figure it out.

Comment: when the variable is to be passed between build steps in the freestyle project you are supposed to use environment variables not parameters. If you use parameter the change in parameter value will be limited to the build step and will not go through. Better to create an environment variable and the update it through the steps.